# Hyphen for compound acronyms

Tags: glossaries

In German language compound words have to be connected using a hyphen. I have some English acronyms not containing a hyphen, e.g. "Machine Learning". If I combine them with another word in my German text, a hyphen has to be added, e.g. Machine-Learning-Modell (english: machine learning model).

I'm using the `glossaries-extra` package for acronyms. By writing `\acl{ML}-Modell` it produces "Machine Learning-Modell". How can I force it to replace the space with a hyphen in this cases? Of course, I could write it in plain text, but I want the occurrence to be listed in my list of acronyms.

Is there a way to overwrite the long text once? Or does anyone even have an automated solution in case the character following the acronym is a hyphen?

Comment: use `Machine\ Learning` in the definition, then `{\let\ -\acl{ML}-Modell}` when you want a `-` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you use `\`  for spaces in the definition you can locally define that to be `-` if there is a following hyphen. I use `\futurelet` here not `\@ifnextchar` so that it does not skip over white space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\acl[1]{Machine\ Learning} % glossaries package, simplified:-)

\NewCommandCopy\oldacl\acl




\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\acl}[1]{\@ifnextchar-{{\let\ -\oldacl{#1}}}{\oldacl{#1}}}
\makeatother

aaa \acl{ml} bbb   \acl{ml}-foo ccc


\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\acl{m}{\def\aclnext{\oldacl{#1}}\futurelet\acltmp\aclinner}
\newcommand\aclinner{{\ifx\acltmp-\let\ -\fi\aclnext}}
\makeatother


aaa \acl{ml} bbb   \acl{ml}-foo ccc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David, you're awesome.
For those of you who want to better understand \futurelet: The following document helped me a lot: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-3/tb22bechtolsheim.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Following @david-carlisle's comment the following works for me:

```
\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\oldacl\acl
\renewcommand{\acl}[1]{\@ifnextchar-{{\let\ -\oldacl{#1}}}{\oldacl{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Don't forget to use `\`  in the definition (e.g. `Machine\ Learning`).

`\acl{ML}-Modell` now produces "Machine-Learning-Modell" while `\acl{ML}` still compiles to "Machine Learning".

Comment: it's safer to use `\NewCommandCopy` than `\let` to copy latex das then the  internal details get copied too, also `\@ifnextchar` will skip space looking for `-` you (might) prefer to use `\futurelet`  directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I updated my answer for the `\NewCommandCopy`.

I also tried to replace `\@ifnextchar` by `\futurelet` for a while but couldn't manage to get it running. I found out that the former uses the latter but I'm not familiar with those macros. Do you have any further advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid special instructions in the acronym definition by using internally a command that replaces spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hnewacronym}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \SPACEORHYPHEN }
  \exp_args:NnnV \newacronym {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\NewCommandCopy{\originalacl}{\acl}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\acl}{m}
 {
  \peek_charcode:NTF -
   {
    \hutter_acl:nn { 1 } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \hutter_acl:nn { 0 } { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hutter_acl:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set:Npe \SPACEORHYPHEN { \int_if_odd:nTF { #1 } { - } { ~ } }
  \originalacl{#2}
  \group_end:
 }

% Initialize
\cs_new_protected:Npn \SPACEORHYPHEN { ~ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\hnewacronym{ML}{ML}{Machine Learning}

\begin{document}

We describe a \acl{ML}-Model

\acl{ML} is interesting

\end{document}
```

[image]

If *all* of your acronyms should follow the rule, you can replace the first definition with

```
\NewCommandCopy{\originalnewacronym}{\newacronym}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\newacronym}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #3 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ~ } { \SPACEORHYPHEN }
  \exp_args:NnnV \originalnewacronym {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
 }
```

so you can directly use `\newacronym`.